# OP_HASH160: Computing script hash in a concrete P2SH transaction

Tags: hash, p2sh

I'm having troubles with understanding how script hash is computed in P2SH transactions.

From BIP-16 documentation (https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0016.mediawiki):

```
scriptSig: [signature] {[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG}
scriptPubKey: OP_HASH160 [20-byte-hash of {[pubkey] OP_CHECKSIG} ] OP_EQUAL
```

From Bitcoin Wiki (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Crypto):

```
OP_HASH160 ... The input is hashed twice: first with SHA-256 and then with RIPEMD-160.
```

So I've tried to compute script hash from a real transaction. I've randomly chosen this one: https://blockstream.info/tx/00e07f279dd05b9b68c40f21b43c57847e75c35cd3bbc2d80921eb037ef0c9a8?expand.

Next, I will be talking about input 0.
I believe that the hash, which I'm supposed to get is

> 4bf411df4b0004e00006f88a4f83d127195b88c7

And the thing, that I'm supposed to hash is

> 5221036c3735b2bf370501c3b872498de54b39ab5afa83d8ce7f6aec43f63a812265b421032b03a42faf387dd5c604435cd48d26b8827fa28a5d4d0f9a18b5cefe443bb4102102ebbd4ecea67dd980fc4854cc13b1f10cefafdafe8b1eb8e5ce73939b59a0477c53ae

, as this is hex of the redeem script.

But when I compute HASH160, I get

> 94b1c88916b7c784b896be91b6924f15c2d4a344

, which is not, what I expect..

> SHA256(5221036c3735b2bf370501c3b872498de54b39ab5afa83d8ce7f6aec43f63a812265b421032b03a42faf387dd5c604435cd48d26b8827fa28a5d4d0f9a18b5cefe443bb4102102ebbd4ecea67dd980fc4854cc13b1f10cefafdafe8b1eb8e5ce73939b59a0477c53ae) = a77da07651b8445cc38ff5bb96e1e38977c4efdcc21b767ca3e25b8919514e03

> RIPEMD160(a77da07651b8445cc38ff5bb96e1e38977c4efdcc21b767ca3e25b8919514e03) = 94b1c88916b7c784b896be91b6924f15c2d4a344

Please explain to me, where is the mistake and what should I do instead. Am I mistaking in what should be hashed and what the result should be, or am I just computing SHA256 and RIPEMD160 wrong?

Good luck,
0x309.

PS: To compute hashes I run `echo"..." | openssl sha256`, then I copy the hash (so that there is no "(stdin)= ") and run
`echo "..." | openssl rmd160`.

Comment: Are you hashing the SHA256 output in hex notation? You need to convert it back to binary first before feeding to ripemd160.

Comment: @PieterWuille, I don't really understand in what format openssl expects inputs and outputs. Is that ASCII? If yes, then I guess that's not what I need. How do I hash it right?

Comment: openssl hashes the input as provided in bytes, but outputs the hash encoded in hexadecimal. So if you do what you're doing, it's not hashing the 32-byte SHA256 output itself, but the 64-character hex encoding of the SHA256 output.

Comment: @PieterWuille, what do you mean by "as provided in bytes"? It has to somehow represent the input string anyway.. And I believe, that representation is not in hex, as ``` echo "hello" | openssl sha256 ``` will work. So how do I specify, that what I'm feeding openssl with is in hex?

Comment: @PieterWuille, or just please tell me whether I understood what should be hashed and what the result should be correctly.

Comment: openssl reads from stdin *bytes* to hash. You're giving it (in both invocations) hex-encoded bytes. So when you're giving it input "9ac7", you really want to give it byte 0x9a followed by byte 0xc7 instead. A possibility is feeding it through `xxd -r -p` which will do this conversion for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been computing hash wrong. Right way to do it:

`echo "hex-encoded script" | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256 | sed "s/[^ ]* //" | xxd -r -p | openssl rmd160`

Or in a more elegant way:

`echo "hex-encoded script" | xxd -r -p | openssl sha256 --binary | openssl rmd160`

Look at the question's comment section, if you are interested why so.

Good luck, 0x309.

PS: you might need to use `openssl rmd160 -provider legacy`

Comment: If you do the first hash with `openssl sha256 -binary` you don't need the sed and (second) xxd. Also in some shells instead of piping echo you can do `xxd -p -r <<<thehexstring`.

Comment: Thank you for your note @dave_thompson_085! You are right. Added your way to the answer.